# Are metrics that determine the same topology, equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've just completed an exercise where I had to prove that two equivalent metrics induce the same topology. Now, I was wondering if it's true that two metrics that induce the same topology, are equivalent? If it's not the case, what are some counterexamples?

Comment: I thought that was the definition of equivalent metrics.

Comment: No, two metrics can induce the same topology, while not being equivalent. There's a well-known example of an operation you can do to a metric, giving you a new metric inducing the same topology, but which does not preserve the uniform structure. But it escapes my memory at the moment :(

Comment: How do you define equivalent metrics?

Comment: I use the definition that two metrics $d_1,d_2$ are equivalent if for all $x,y\in X$ then $h \cdot d_1(x,y)\leq d_2(x,y) \leq k \cdot d_1(x,y)$ for some $h,k>0$

Comment: @Randall.  It is or to be completely clear, topologically equivalent as compared to uniformly equivalent which ziggurism mention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on the set $X$ are equivalent if there exist $a,b>0$ such that
$$
ad_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)\le bd_1(x,y)
$$
for every $x,y\in X$.

The usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $\delta(x,y)=\lvert\arctan x-\arctan y\rvert$  on $\mathbb{R}$ induce the same topologies, but are not equivalent: indeed $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with respect to the former and not complete with respect to the latter (the sequence of natural numbers is Cauchy for $\delta$).

Comment: That is the definition of uniformly equivalent, a much stronger definition than topologically equivalent.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Indeed! But it's the definition used by the OP, see the comments below the question. This shows uniform equivalence is stronger than topological equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an unbounded metric space $(X,d)$. Then $d/(d+1)$ is also a metric on $X$ which is bounded (so not (bi-Lipschitz-)equivalent to $X$), but which gives the same topology on $X$ (because $x\mapsto x/(x+1)$ is strictly increasing).

Comment: I think this may be the example I was trying to remember. It's probably the case that functions which are uniformly continuous with respect to $d/(1+d)$ are not necessarily uniformly continuous under $d$, would that be right?

Comment: @ziggurism: No. If you have a function with modulus of continuity $\delta$ with respect to $d$, then $\delta/(\delta+1)$ will surely work for $d/(d+1)$. Loosely speaking, I believe the fine structure given by the two metrics is the same, only the coarse structures are (vastly) different.

Comment: What do you mean by fine/coarse structure?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure for the coarse structure. By fine structure, I don't mean anything precise, just the broad idea of local behaviour, complementary to the coarse one.